# Airflow: Storing machine learning model

Tags: python, machine-learning, airflow

I'd make pipeline of machine learning on Airflow.
Example)

```
result = model.fit()
```

But DAG file:(*sample.py*) is refreshed on each times.

[image]

So I can't store trained model.

How should I treat **trained model**?

Or should I store the trained model data in external?
Then take the trained model in use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the model in pickle file and retrieve the model from same file whenever you want.

```
import pickle 
result = model.fit()
# save the model to disk
filename = 'my_model.sav'
pickle.dump(model, open(filename, 'wb'))

# load the model from file for later use
reload_model = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))
result_final = reload_model.score(X_test, y_test)
print result_final
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer. I'll try to store the model as pickle.